# Why does Lightning Data Service fails quietly when trying to load converted lead?

Tags: lightning-data-service

I was hoping to make subsequent request by picking up ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedOpportunityId, etc, but seems that is not possible - will I have to fallback to Apex?

Is that expected behaviour? Why there is not errors generated?

```
<force:recordData aura:id="DataService"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      mode="EDIT"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId || v.pageReference.state.lead}"
                      targetFields="{!v.lead}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"/>
```

I am guessing this is over-smartification from Salesforce side as this record is loaded in EDIT mode?

Comment: This is really interesting - could you elaborate at all on the order of operations? That is, do you convert the lead while the page is open and attempt to reload, or do you simply see the failure at the time of loading the lead page when the lead is converted? Does "fail quietly" mean `force:recordData` loads nothing?

Comment: I cannot find recordUpdated  in force:Recorddata https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/specification